# st.sidebar.selectbox takes the first column name as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm facing an issue while integrating the pandas dataframe with streamlit app. My code is:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

csv_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a CSV file", type="csv")

if csv_file is not None:
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    column_names = data.columns.tolist()
    column_selection = st.selectbox("Select a Column (or Text Column)",column_names)
    for text in (data[column_selection]):
        st.write(text)
```

what actually happening is, `column_selection` takes first column name as default value. While I want to use the column value that I select by myself. This what I'm getting:
[image]
As it takes the `reference-ID` by default.
Can anyone please suggest what I did wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Select some other column in the select widget and watch the changes.

Comment: It looks weird as I don't want this error to be reflected as `reference-ID` gets executed by its own.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the `st.selectbox` to default to the first column (or any column). You can work around this with the following solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# making some test data
(
    pd.DataFrame(data=[[*range(3)]], columns=list("abc"))
    .to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
)

csv_file = st.file_uploader(label="Upload a CSV file")

if csv_file is not None:
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    # The default value of `st.selectbox` is the 0th element in `options`
    # I added a placeholder and then the rest of the columns
    column_names = ["Select", *data.columns]
    column_selection = st.selectbox(
        label="Select a Column (or Text Column)", options=column_names
    )
    # if the user does not select a column, the rest of the script won't run
    if column_selection != "Select":
        for text in data[column_selection]:
            st.write(text)
```

#### Nothing selected

[image: nothing selected]

#### Something selected

[image: something selected]

## Resources

- https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/949
- [No-Default Selectbox (3rd party package)](https://extras.streamlit.app/No-Default%20Selectbox)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation for version 1.25.0](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.selectbox) (see the part about `placeholder`):

> **A selectbox can't be empty**, so a placeholder only displays while a user's cursor is in a selectbox after manually deleting the current selection. **A future update will allow selectboxes to be empty**.

[The answer by Ian Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76821202/14909621) is clever, but I believe this will cause problems in case the dummy "Select" phrase is the actual column name. We can't use an empty string, `None`, `NaN` as well, because they can also be column names. So we have to produce a unique phrase for each set of columns and use formatting to replace it with a placeholder, for example like this:

```
...
dummy = 'dummy' + ''.join(map(str, data.columns))  # need an additional 'dummy' part in case of a single column with empty string as it's name
placeholder = "Select a column..."
selected_col = st.selectbox(
    "Select a column:", 
    data.columns.insert(0, dummy), 
    format_func=lambda x: placeholder if x == dummy else x,
    placeholder=placeholder
)
if selected_col != dummy: 
    st.write(data[selected_col])
...
```

In addition to this we can save `dummy` value in `streamlit.session_state` to avoid calculating it when selecting a different column.

I think we can do better with [streamlit.multiselect](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.multiselect). It's empty by default. It allows to restrict a number of selected columns by `max_selections=1` if needed. And it returns always a list of selections which is empty if nothing selected. So we have no troubles with weird names like `None` or an empty string. The code can be like this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

csv_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(
    "Upload a CSV file", type="csv", 
    # note in a session_state that file was changed - need to reload data
    on_change=lambda: st.session_state.update({'file_changed': True})
)

if st.session_state.get('file_changed'):
    # load data only when a new file selected
    st.session_state['file_changed'] = False
    if csv_file:
        st.session_state['data'] = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        st.sidebar.write('Loaded new data from', csv_file.name)
    else:
        st.session_state['data'] = None
        st.sidebar.write('Data was cleared')

data = st.session_state.get('data')
if data is not None:
    # if more then 1 columns then show the slider and selection widgets
    if len(data.columns) > 1:
        max_selections = st.sidebar.slider("Max number of columns to select", 1, len(data.columns)) 
        selected_col = st.sidebar.multiselect(
            "Select a column:", 
            data.columns, 
            placeholder="What's up?", 
            max_selections=max_selections
        )
        if selected_col: st.dataframe(data[selected_col])
    else:
        st.sidebar.write(f'Data have only a column {data.columns[0]!r}')
        st.dataframe(data)
```

How it looks:

[image: UI of streamlit]